Best Practice of using Navigation Component. Activities only or only Fragments or Both of them together?
I am working with Navigation in android and multiple questions came up:

If an android application only consist of activities, is it good practice to make NavGraph for activities?

Or NavGraph should only be used with Fragments ?

Or NavGraph can used with both Fragment and Activities ?


Example Scenario 1 : Android application contains HomeActivity with a Bottom Navigation View then while creating nav_graph what will be startDestination activity or fragment of bottom navigation view ?
Example Scenario 2 : Android application contains HomeActivity with a Navigation Drawer then while creating nav_graph what will be the startDestination ?

Usually this component is suited for Single Activity Multiple Fragment arch
